# How to draw scatter chart with labels on google chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, label, google-visualization

Look at this Google chart in [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bboygA0H9r0OgjAF7y4ixdJOqSf2rbHoXAy204lFBaE/edit#gid=0).

How to draw this names on chart rather than tooltips? Is there need to change in data or options given to Google chart?

You can check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hOJqGi?p=preview).

```
var chart2 = {};
chart2.type = "ScatterChart";
chart2.cssStyle = "height:400px; width:500px;";
chart2.data = [
      ['Age', 'Weight'],
      [ {'v':8,'f':'Name 1'},      -12],
      [ {'v':-4,'f':'Name 2'},      5.5],
      [ {'v':11,'f':'Name 3'},     14],
      [ {'v':-4,'f':'Name 4'},      -5],
      [ {'v':3,'f':'Name 5'},      3.5],
      [ {'v':6.5,'f':'Name 6'},    -7]
    ];

chart2.options = {
    "title": "Age Vs Maturity",
    "isStacked": "true",
    "fill": 20,
    "hAxis": {"title": "Age", minValue: -15, maxValue: 15},
    "vAxis": {"title": "Maturity", minValue: -15, maxValue: 15},
    "legend": 'none'
};

$scope.chart2 = chart2;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use an annotation column to add labels to a scatter chart...

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Age', 'Weight', {role: 'annotation'}],
      [ 8,      12, 'Point 1'],
      [ 1,      5.5, 'Point 2'],
      [ 11,     14, 'Point 3'],
      [ 4,      5, 'Point 4'],
      [ 3,      3.5, 'Point 5'],
      [ 6.5,    7, 'Point 6']
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Age vs. Weight comparison',
      hAxis: {title: 'Age', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
      vAxis: {title: 'Weight', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
      legend: 'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Yes. Then it is Bubble chart. I have added that in my plunk. I wanted to have scatter chart and then add labels to it. Do you know how to do that?