# legends and url on google graph points

Tags: google-visualization

I have a scattergraph with several points on it.

I'd like to have some text and possibly an url, so I can go to the page specially for that item represented by that point.

(The graph is wholesale price vs sales price, I want the legend to show the item number, title, and go the product page for that item when I click on the point)

I get the data as json via ajax; part of the data is

```
'
    "rows": [
    {"c": [{"v": 24,"f": null},{"v": 399,"f": null}]},
    {"c": [{"v": 24.9,"f": null},{"v": 369,"f": null}]},
....
```

`

I haven't been able to find documentation on how to do it, but I'm sure I have seen it.

Comment: when you say "I'd like to have some text", do you mean when the point is hovered? that would be a _tooltip_, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39251024/5090771) -- or always visible, without hover, that would be an _annotation_, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37943366/5090771) -- to open a url "on click", use the `'select'` event, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38598129/5090771)

Comment: I'd like a tooltip with the current X/Y values (which it have now) and some extra text. Then a click would open an URL.